# XSL Transforming comments

Tags: xml, xslt, comments, xslt-1.0

I am using XSLT1.0 to transform some XML to another XML. Just needs to do some processing of contents.

The input XML has some comments which is in an expanded charater entity form. I would need it to make it like a regular comment.

The input is as below,

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
    `<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd">`

`<concept id="test">`
`<title>Test title</title>`
         `<conbody>&lt;!-- test comments--&gt;`

`<p>test paragraph &lt;!-- comments in p --&gt;</p>`

`</conbody>`
    `</concept>`

The required output comment should be like below,

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
    `<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd">`

`<concept id="test">`
`<title>Test title</title>`
         `<conbody><!-- test comments-->`

`<p>test paragraph <!-- comments in p --></p>`

`</conbody>`
    `</concept>`

The comment should actually come like above. But I am not sure whether it is possible to do it in XSLT.

Can someone help on this?

Comment: The code is
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: Well do you know that the `test` elements contain always such a comment and nothing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***- edited in response to clarification -***

Perhaps it could be as simple as this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming your processing chain supports DOE.

It is also assuming that your XML does not carry other escaped markup that should not be unescaped. If that's not a safe assumption, then use:

```
<xsl:template match="text()" name="unescape-comments">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&lt;!--')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&lt;!--')"/> 
            <xsl:comment>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($text, '&lt;!--'), '--&gt;')"/>
            </xsl:comment>
            <xsl:call-template name="unescape-comments">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '--&gt;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But actually the comment can come anywhere in any element. Also the parent element can contain some other plane text or even sub elements. So the main purpose of the Xslt is to keep the same content taking care of the comments. The input XML is generated out of a script which is making the comments inside invalid. Trying to make the XML valid using XSLT.

Comment: Please edit your question and show a **representative** example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: Modified the question with sample input and expected output

Comment: See my modified answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. I just modified the code so that only the comments will get expanded in output. There can be some other character entities which should be retained same as the input

Comment: @Gpn008 Okay, you need to do the full package then. What you tried will fail if the text contains more than one comment.